# My ASP.Net Application raised HTTP 500.22 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have problems programming the web with mvc. I use visual studio 2017. I am not good at English so I don't know what is this error. Please help me to differentiate it. Sincerely thank you.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste text as text into the question. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text.

Comment: What is your pool's CLR version set to? What .NET version is your app?